# PowerShell optimize-Volume throwing error

Tags: powershell

I am creating an automation to optimize the C drive in my environment but when I run the below PowerShell command its throwing an error.(I am running this command on virtual Hard Disk VHDX)

> Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter C -Defrag -Verbose

I have checked Both defragsvc (Defragmentation service) and Microsoft Storage SMP services are running. Can any one please help me on this?

**Error**

```
Optimize-Volume : Failed
Activity ID: {288b5478-2fd1-4159-8a4f-237d1484c50c}
At line:1 char:1
 Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter C -Defrag -Verbose
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: 
(StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/MSFT_Volume) [Optimize-Volume], 
CimException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 4,Optimize-Volume
```

Comment: Did you inspect the eventlog 'Application' --> 'Microsoft-Windows-Defrag' to see if that sheds more light on the error?

Comment: This isn't my cup of tea, so I'm just searching the web to see what is out there.  Found this page where it someone had a similar issue and looks like it was solved: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/windows-2016-optimize-volume-retrim.82686/